# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Where
$$x_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x_n}{2} & \text{if } x_n \text{ is even}
\\
\frac{1+x_n}2 & \text{if } x_n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

and $x_0\gt0$ and $n\geq0$.

Any idea on how to approach this problem with elementary methods?

Comment: What are *your* thoughts on the problem? Have you tried to compute the sequence for some small initial values? Does that lead to some conjecture?

Comment: @MartinR I tried, $x_n=x$ but got stuck afterwards.

Comment: This looks a lot like the Collatz conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: @HenryLee except crucially in this, $\forall x:x_{n+1}\leq x_n$

Comment: @user334732 yes true good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function takes a natural number $x_n$ and spits out $x_n/2$, rounded up. We can observe that if $x_n = 1, x_{n+1} = 1$. Otherwise, for any other $x_n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n > x_{n+1}$. Furthermore, observe that $x_i$ is always a natural number if $x_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. This suffices in showing that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n =1$.

Got it? Try this one: $$x_{n+1} = \begin{cases} 
      x_n / 2 & \text{if } x_n \text{ is even}\\
      3x_n + 1 & \text{if } x_n \text{ is odd}
   \end{cases} $$

What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$?

(I'm kidding, don't try it unless you want to be working forever, or you are a real genius.)

Comment: Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

The limit is $1$ (assuming that $x_0\in\Bbb N$.)

**Proof.** Define $f:[1,x_0]\to\Bbb [1,x_0]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac x2 &, \space x\equiv0\pmod 2
\\ \frac{x+1}2&,\space x\equiv1\pmod 2\end{cases}$. Then your $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$.

Convince yourself that $f$ is a contraction with the unique fixed point $x=1$. Then, after the [Banach fixed-point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), the limit of the $x_n$ equals $1$.

Comment: Is there any way of proving this w\out the Banach fixed-point Theorem?

Comment: Your professor (or whoever) will probably be ok with you mentioning such a well-known Theorem

Comment: The problem is that I've yet to learn this Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

From the problem statement we infer that $x_n$ is an integer (and the iterations leave it so).

We observe that

$$x_n>1\implies 1\le\frac{x_n}2,\frac{1+x_n}2<x_n,$$
(you don't need to care about parity) and
$$x_n=1\implies\frac{1+x_n}2=1.$$

Hence the sequence decreases to $1$ from any $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the starting point $x_0$ is an integer, then all of the other $x_j$s are integers, and furthermore, the following is true too: If $x_n$ is an integer larger than 1, then $1 \le x_{n+1} < x_n$ [note the second inequality is this string is *strict*]. However, if $x_n=1$, then $x_{n+1}=x_{n+2} = \ldots = 1$. And finally, if $x_n$ is an integer smaller than 1, then $x_n < x_{n+1} \le 1$. [here note the first inequality is this string is *strict*]

Convince yourself that this implies three things:

1. If $x_0$ is an integer larger than 1, then there is an integer $j$; $j \le x_0-1$ such that $x_j=1$, and $x_n=1$ for each $n\ge j$.
2. If $x_0$ is 1 then all of the $x_j$s are 1.
3. If $x_0$ is an integer less than 1, then there is an integer $j$; $j \le |x_0|+1$; such that $x_j=1$, and $x_n=1$ for each $n\ge j$.

Then convince yourself that 1. 2., and 3. together imply that the limit of your sequence is always 1 no matter which integer $x_0$ the sequence starts at.

Answer (score 0):

One nice proof of this is that the function is closed to the positive integers and for every positive integer other than $1$, $x_{n+1}< x_n$.

Then it follows from the **well-founded** property of the positive integers that it converges to $1$.

Well-foundedness means no descending sequence continues indefinitely.